# Drawing 100+ circles with different position using UIBezierPaths

Tags: ios, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw 100+ UIBezierPath circles in the drawRect function of an UIView. I am creating and adding the UIBezierPaths to an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:centerPoint radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:360 clockwise:YES];

    path.lineWidth = 2;
    [bezierPaths addObject:path];
}
```

before calling the setNeedDisplay. Then in drawRect I iterate through the array

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

       for (UIBezierPath *path in bezierPaths) {
            [path fill];
            [path stroke];
       }
    }
```

This looks like an overkill, is there a better way of doing this? Using Profile I can see that the 86% of the MainThread is being used on calling the [path stroke] in drawRect.

Comment: Is the center point the only thing that is different?

Comment: Do the circles change their positions?

Comment: Hi David, I managed to answer it myself ... I am passing 0 and 360 degrees as opposed to radiants and it is drawing them too many times. Unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation to 'Answer Your Question'. Thanks for taking the time though!

Comment: You can (and is encouraged to) answer your own question and accept it so that others who might have the same problem can benefit from your solution.

Comment: You didn't read my entire comment above :] - "Unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation to 'Answer Your Question'. Thanks for taking the time though!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am passing 0 and 360 degrees as opposed to radiants and it is drawing them too many times.